# Passing objects with circular reference to XPC services

Tags: swift, circular-reference, xpc

I would like to pass objects with circular to an XPC service.

Let's say that I have an object class *Course* a *Teacher* and an array of *Student*. Student have also a reference to the *Teacher*.

The XPC protocol signatures contain any combination of the three objects. How can I implement `NSSecureCoding` when dealing with such references?